# Refresh ListView with button INSIDE adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have my ListAdapter

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Todo> implements OnCheckedChangeListener, OnClickListener
```

Inside

```
@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ....
  }
```

I have

```
ImageButton btn_delete = (ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
btn_delete.setId(position);
btn_delete.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Inside `onClick()` I delete a row from database (using the position I saved on the view previously).
After that I want to see my ListView updated.
Which instruction I should use in `OnClick` to do that?

I tried with `notifyDataSetChanged()` but it doesn't seem to work.

**SOLUTION**

I only deleted the row from database but forgot to update the values of Adapter. After doing that, `notifyDataSetChanged()` works perfectly!

Comment: You must be populating your listview from database... so do one thing make a specific fucntion from where you fetch your values and call it before calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an `Internal SQLite database` you should use a `CursorAdaper` with `CursorLoader`. This way you app not only become more responsive but also automatically update the listview when a change is occured in the database.